# How to persist object on http request destroy in spring web 4.3

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have an object which represents user's state with a huge amount of data and this object can be mutated multiple times per one http request, so one of the optimization I want to use is persist this object only on http request destruction.

The problem is when I try to use @PreDestroy annotation on request scope bean I can not use request scope dependencies like http session (e.g. call `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest#getSession()`), because DispatcherServlet reset all request scope beans in `org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet#processRequest`

```java
            resetContextHolders(request, previousLocaleContext, previousAttributes);
            if (requestAttributes != null) {
                requestAttributes.requestCompleted();
            }
```

The method annotated with PreDestroy is typically used to release resources that it has been holding, however I want to commit transaction using lot of dependencies, that's why it does not work.

Is there any way in spring web to call bean's method after Servlet::doService call and before request scope beans reset?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Global `ServletContextListener`. which needs to register the callback at bean level, the `ServletContextListener` registers the callback at `context` level.

```
public class MyServletContextListener
  implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        System.out.println(
          "Executed callback ContextListener.");
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // Triggers when context initializes
    }
}
```

You need to register it to the `ServletListenerRegistrationBean` in the configuration class:

```
@Bean
ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ServletContextListener> servletListener() {
    ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ServletContextListener> srb
      = new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<>();
    srb.setListener(new MyServletContextListener());
    return srb;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how `Context` level event can call request bound beans before `org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder#resetRequestAttributes`.
Unfortunately, even `ServletRequestListener#requestDestroyed` has called after `RequestContextHolder#resetRequestAttributes`.